# Cannot retrieve values from added rows (jquery) in JSP using servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, dynamic, html-table

I have a table wherein you can add a row when you click the addRowButton. Here is the code for it:

```
$('#addRowButton').click(function () {
                        $('#data').append(
                                '<tr>' +
                                '<td>IGA01</td>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                                '<input type="text" name="description" class="form-control no-border" id="description" placeholder="Enter Institutional Graduate Attribute">' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</td>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                                '<input type="text" name="remarks" class="form-control no-border" id="remarks">' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</td>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"> </i></button>' +
                                '<button type="button" id="deleteRow" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>' +
                                '</td>' +
                                '</tr>'
                                );
```

My problem is when I try to retrieve the values of the added rows I cannot get them. I can only retrieve the values of rows that were not dynamically added. . Here is the code of the servlet (The for loop is for me to see whether the servlet was able to retrieve the inputs):

```
    String[] codeIGA = request.getParameterValues("codeIGA");
    String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description");
    String[] remarks = request.getParameterValues("remarks");

    for (int y = 0; y < codeIGA.length; y++) {
        System.out.println("codeIGA: " + codeIGA[y]);
        System.out.println("description: " + description[y]);
        System.out.println("remarks: " + remarks[y]);
    }
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I couldn't retrieve the values in the added rows was because I was getting `codeIGA.length` for my for loop when as seen in my add row function I forgot to add `<input type="hidden" name="codeIGA" class="readonlyWhite" id="codeIGA" value="" />`.